# How to log value that cause unique key violation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am inserting data into a table from temp table as below:

```
INSERT INTO TBL_PERSON (PropertyID, PERSONID, FULLNAME)          
SELECT DISTINCT PropertyID, PERSONID, FULLNAME FROM #SalesContacts
```

The unique key constraint is defined in `Tbl_Person` using combination of `PropertyId`, `PersonId` and `FullName` columns.

When this query is executed, how can I find out which combination of values are causing unique key constraint exceptions?

I want to log these values with the exception message.

Comment: You could try the INTERSECT clause

    SELECT DISTINCT PropertyID, PERSONID, FULLNAME FROM #SalesContacts 
 INTERSECT
 SELECT  PropertyID, PERSONID, FULLNAME FROM TBL_PERSON

see this link for details on the INTERSECT clause

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx

Comment: That's good. But I want to get the values directly in catch block of try-catch.

Comment: Hmm, i think that might be problematic - Sql Server would stop at the 'first' duplicate and pass control to the CATCH block.  what if there are multiple duplicates - it would seem you would want to check for ALL duplicates before trying the insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is there a reason this logic won't work for you?

```
--Find all duplicates and save to temp table
select * into #Duplicates from
(
    SELECT DISTINCT PropertyID, PERSONID, FULLNAME FROM #SalesContacts 
    INTERSECT
    SELECT  PropertyID, PERSONID, FULLNAME FROM TBL_PERSON
) a

--Log the duplicates
insert into ErrorLoggingTable(PropertyID, PERSONID, FULLNAME, ErrorMessage)
select PropertyID, PERSONID, FULLNAME, 'Duplicate Found' from #Duplicates

--Remove the duplicates from the #SalesContacts table
delete a from #SalesContacts a join
#Duplicates b on b.PropertyID and b.PersonID and b.FullName

--Insert the rest
insert into TBL_PERSON (PropertyID, PERSONID, FULLNAME)
    select PropertyID, PERSONID, FULLNAME
```

Comment: That is fine. I think we can not catch the exception causing values direct in catch block if try-catch.